# IntelliJ http client save JSON value has enviroment variable don´t work. Autorization Token Keycloak

Tags: json, intellij-idea, environment-variables, keycloak, response

This example code adapted to our test does not work:

```
### Authorization by token, part 1. Retrieve and save token.
POST https://httpbin.org/post
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "token": "my-secret-token"
}

> {% client.global.set("auth_token", response.body.json.token); %}

### Authorization by token, part 2. Use token to authorize.
GET https://httpbin.org/headers
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}

###
```

when you use the IntelliJ http client adapting the example to save a response token, it does not work and fails:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="Bearer token is malformed"
```

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the reproducible test case.

Answer (score 0):

with this code it works:

```
> {% client.global.set("access_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body)).access_token);%}
```

replacing access_token with whatever it is called

to paint the response for debug on the Intellij response Handler window:

```
> {%client.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body)).access_token);client.global.set("access_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body)).access_token);%}
```

A complete example:

POST https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/yourrealms/protocol/openid-connect/token
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&client_id=theclientid&username=theusername&password=thepassword&scope=openid&email&profile&client_secret=cc1f0-theclientsecret-06dabdd89

> {%
> client.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body)).access_token);
> client.global.set("access_token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.body)).access_token);
> %}

#### yourapi

GET http://localhost:8080/api/yourapi
authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
cache-control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic cc1f0-theclientsecret-06dabdd89